# Mac OS X Apache not starting

Tags: macos, apache, ssl, proxypass

When I start my apache server, it fails and quits. I've narrowed the problem down to this lines in my custom configuration file:

**ProxyPass /xxx-web/intern/rpc-gwt ajp:/127.0.0.1:8009/xxx-web/intern/rpc-gwt
ProxyPassReverse /xxx-web/intern/rpc-gwt ajp:/127.0.0.1:8009/xxx-web/intern/rpc-gwt**

There is one strange entry in the error log:

**Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]**

I am using the standard http.conf, running Apache 2.2.26 on OS X 10.9.5

The ProxyPass is **not** in a VirtualHost tag.

The configuration file works fine on a similar Apache installation on Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this Apache out of the box? that is, are you running the Apache that came with your OSX10? edit: also check your httpd.conf file, look to what httpd-ssl.conf file it's pointing to and make sure it's update to date and actually exists.

Comment: Yes, it is a completely out of the box setup. The httpd-ssl.conf was commented out. I added it, confirmed its existence, but I get the same error.